# How to set conditional parameters? I would like to prompt user for 3 symptoms but if user types 'end' then intent is finished

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to make a medical diagnosis chatbot. The general idea is that the bot prompts the user for symptoms.
The user must input at least 1 symptom and a maximum of 3 symptoms.

The end of conversation is reached when user does one of the following:

- Inputs 3 symptoms OR
- Types 'end' after inputting at least 1 symptom

**Example 1 (3 symptoms):**

Bot: Hello! Diagnosis Bot at your service here. Please type in the symptoms you are having.

User: Cough

Bot: Gotcha! Please type in another symptom.

User: Fever

Bot: Roger that. Please type in another symptom.

User: Phlegm

Bot: I have received the following symptoms: Cough, Fever, Phlegm. Give me a few seconds to calculate your diagnosis.....

// This part will connect to a custom built AI engine

**Example 2 (2 symptoms):**

Bot: Hello! Diagnosis Bot at your service here. Please type in the symptoms you are having.

User: Chest pain

Bot: Gotcha! Please type in another symptom.

User: Dizziness

Bot: Roger that. Please type in another symptom.

User: End

Bot: I have received the following symptoms: Chest pain, Dizziness. Give me a few seconds to calculate your diagnosis.....

To design this chat bot, I have setup the following:

- A 'symptom' entity
- A 'Get Started' intent
- A 'symptom-input' intent which requires 3 symptom parameters.

**Question:**
I would like to set it up so that at any point the user types 'end' to any of the prompts then it finishes the symptom-input intent and invokes the symptom-end intent. How do I do so?

**Symptom entity:**
[image: Symptom entity:]

**Get Started intent:**
[image: Get Started intent]

**symptom-input intent:**
[image: symptom-input intent]

**symptom-end intent:**
[image: symptom-end intent]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a good design, how would the user know that he can finish the input with the 'end' keyword? It would be better if your agent would simply accept a list of symptoms like so:

Bot: Hello! Diagnosis Bot at your service here. Please tell me what symptoms you are having.

User: I'm having fever, dizziness and chest pain.

Bot: Ok, give me a few seconds to calculate your diagnosis.....

All you have to do for that is to check the `list` box next to the symptom parameter in the parameter table of your symptom-input intent. This would make your dialog shorter and more intuitive and save you the need for a separate symptom-end intent. See the [documentation on parameters](https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters#is_list) for details.

Comment: Great suggestion. I have 2 follow-up questions: 1) Is it possible to set a max no. of symptom parameters to 3? 2) In my response I was referencing the symptoms like so: `Thank you. I received the following symptoms: $symptom1, $symptom2, $symptom3` Give me a few seconds to calculate.` With the list however, every symptom parameter has value $symptom. How do I go about listing the symptoms correctly in my response?

Comment: Regarding 1) no, there is no way to limit the length of the list. Dialogflow will parse as many parameters as it understood from the user. Regarding 2) you get a a single parameter `symptom`, which is a JSON array (as opposed to a string/number with a non-list parameter). You would have to iterate through this in your backend code.