# How to append parameter to existing parameters list from previous context in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm building a chatbot that asks users for symptoms, one at a time.

There is a single entity @symptom, which is a list. I'd like to figure out how to append each new symptom into the symptoms parameter list from existing contexts.

For example,

**Bot:** Please type in your 1st symptom.

**User:** Cough

`symptoms = ['cough']`

**Bot:** Please type in your 2nd symptom.

**Fever:** Fever

`symptoms = ['cough', 'fever']`

**Bot:** Please type in your 3rd symptom.

**User:** Breathlessness

`symptoms = ['cough', 'fever']`

How do I go about building such a flow?

(N.B. I know I can simply have one intent that asks user to type out all the symptoms in one line, but I'd prefer for the symptoms to be asked one by one so I can ensure data cleansing before inserting the symptom into the list)

Answer (score 2):

This [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596479/how-to-set-conditional-parameters-i-would-like-to-prompt-user-for-3-symptoms-bu) is more of a design issue:) You can roughly achieve what you have described with Follow-up intents and contexts, but a better way would be to more clearly separate the intent and parameter matching from any kind of further backend processing.

You should, if you haven't already, define your `symptom` entity as a [Developer mapping entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#dev_mapping). This gives you the option to map an arbitrary number of synonyms to one reference value:

```
reference value: fever
synonyms: fever, feverishness, high temperature, febricity, febrility
```

The user can now enter any of the synonyms, you will always get the reference value as the parameter (and list of these values if the parameter is a list). The reference value doesn't even have to be a normal word, it can be any unique identifier (e.g. a primary key from database of symptoms). It is only matched if it itself is included in the list of synonyms.

This structure would ensure that you will always get a parameter from a clearly defined set of values, even if the actual user input has a much greater variability. Any further processing of these parameters should be part of your backend code and not be tied to the Dialogflow agent. Ideally you would think of the reference values as the API between the user input and you backend business logic.

Comment: I actually solved my problem earlier today by enabling webhooks and adding symptoms to an array and then return the array in a response via context out instead

Comment: this answer talks about handling synonyms, but original question is about list of items (fever and cough are not synonyms), @doctopus can you add answer how to handle actual list append situation?